# Python Catching Exception But Printing Them

Tags: python, loops, exception, heap, index-error

I have built a max heap and trying to extract max as long as there are elements. If there isn't I'm returning an IndexError. This the code I'm trying to execute:

```
while True:
    try:
        print hp.extract_max()
    except:
        break
```

and in the extract_max() method:

```
def extract_max(self):
    if self.size == 0:
        return IndexError
    item = self.items[0]
    self.items[0] = self.items[self.size - 1]
    self.heapify_down()
    del self.items[len(self.items) - 1]
    return item
```

However, the code is not breaking upon encountering an IndexError, rather printing it too. The **while** loop is not breaking.

```
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>
....
```

it keeps printing the exception, without breaking the loop.

What's the problem?

Comment: It would seem the code posted here is either incomplete or different from what you're running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be raising an exception, not returning it. Do `raise IndexError`.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answer stated, you should `raise` the `exception` instead of `return` so:

```
if self.size == 0:
    raise IndexError
```

I just want to add that you are catching all type of exceptions with `except`, you might want to change it to catch `IndexError` only to avoid catching other exceptions (ex: `KeyboardInterrupt`) as the following:

```
while True:
    try:
        print hp.extract_max()

    except IndexError:
        break
```